# WebDriverWait by class name when there are more class with the same name

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I’m trying to click on a button that has the same class as other 5 buttons.

This code is working but clicks on the first button that finds the class.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".com-ex-5"))).click()
```

How can I click on the 5th button?

This ain’t working :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".com-ex-5")))[5].click()
```

Comment: Have you tried `element_to_be_clickable` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

`presence_of_element_located` returns single element. You need to use `presence_of_all_elements_located`.

So that your code would look like:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    .until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".com-ex-5")))[4]
    .click()
```

**P.S.** - If you need 5th button then you need to pick element by index `4` since indexing starts from `0` in Python

Answer (score 0):

1. In case you want to click on an element you have to use `element_to_be_clickable` `expected_conditions`, not `presence_of_element_located`.
2. In case there is no unique locator for that element (that's strange) you can use XPath to locate that element.
   So, this should work:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//*[contains(@class,'com-ex-5')])[5]"))).click()
```

And in case there are 5 elements matching this locator and this is the last of them, this can be used:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//*[contains(@class,'com-ex-5')])[last()]"))).click()
```